# Set order creation date using CRUD methods and save it in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

I'm developing a custom plugin for Woocommerce and it uses functions provided by some other Woocommerce extension. I've encountered a strange problem with Woocommerce.

Although I've set `date_created` for an order with `$order->set_date_created` but after getting the same order again with `wc_get_order( $order->get_id() )` the returned `$order` object doesn't have `date_created` set and it is `NULL`. The code with comments below should clear, what I'm trying to say:

```
// returns a new order object from order post_id
$order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
$order->set_date_created( time() );

// Getting expected WC_DateTime object
$order->get_date_created();


/***** Here's the problem ******/
$same_order = wc_get_order( $order->get_id() );

// returns NULL instead of WC_DateTime object
$same_order->get_date_created();
```

So my question is why the `date_created` property is vanished while getting the same order again and has not written to database when set. Please help to find the underlying bug and suggest fix for this.

Although, I could've passed the `$order` object around after setting the `date_created` but the function from another plugin expects `order_id` of an order which should have its `date_created` set and not `NULL`. That's why I set `date_created` and then pass `$order->get_id()` to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need also to save the data… try the following instead:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );

// Get an instance of the current WC_DateTime object
$date_time = new WC_DateTime();

// Set it in the order
$order->set_date_created( $date_time );

// Save the data (in database)
$order->save();
```

This time it should works, and you will not get an empty value.

Comment: Thanks. It was silly of me to not find the `$order->save();` method. Sometimes we can't find because we are not very much sure about what we are searching for.  : )